Elementor PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
I have the Jupiter X 4.6.5 theme, WordPress 6.6.1, Elementor 3.23.4, PHP version 8.1.29 and PHP limit at 1024M.
When I did the last update of Elementor my website stopped working and shows this error message ‘There has been a critical error on this website’. The WordPress administration is working but the website is not visible. I have created a staging copy of the website where I am making the changes and where the error is occurring. I have tried everything, I have deactivated and reactivated the plugins one by one, uninstalled and reinstalled elementor and nothing... I have consulted with the technical department of my hosting and they have told me that the error is in the Elementor plugin and that I should contact you to solve it. They have seen this error:

[20-Aug-2024 13:08:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/elydobritz/public_html/staging/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/promotions/module.php on line 51

This is the code on line 51:
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', function( Widgets_Manager $manager ) {
            foreach ( Api::get_promotion_widgets() as $widget_data ) {
                $manager->register( new Widgets\Pro_Widget_Promotion( [], [
                    'widget_name' => $widget_data['name'],
                    'widget_title' => $widget_data['title'],
                ] ) );
            }
        } );

I am already desperate and don't know what to do... My client needs to get his website and online shop back up and running as soon as possible... Can someone help me?
Another thing I tried was to remove the piece of code that I have shown (well commenting it out) and it didn't help, the problem remained the same...

That's not an error, it's a warning, so it won't crash the code - although it does indicate that something isn't quite working as it should (it seems that Api::get_promotion_widgets() doesn't return something you can loop over). If this is a live website, warnings should be logged to a file not displayed on the screen, and therefore the end user should not notice any difference if a warning is generated.

And if the bug is in Elementor itself, which it seems to be, you should raise a bug report with the plugin maintainers to get the code which generated the warning fixed. Stackoverflow is for programmers to ask for help with code they're trying to write themselves (e.g. maybe if you were trying to integrate elementor into your site in some custom way perhaps), we're not technical support for 3rd-party software. Elementor has its own support resources available if you need troubleshooting or help with the plugin itself. (See also the [tour] and [ask] to learn how Stackoverflow works).

I tried was to remove the piece of code that I have shown (well commenting it out) and it didn't help, the problem remained the same...this seems extremely unlikely, unless either a) this isn't actually the right bit of the code, or b) you somehow edited the wrong copy of the file, or c) it still produced warnings/errors, but slightly different ones, perhaps about another area of the code. It's unclear. If this is the source of the error then commenting it out would definitely stop the warning appearing....

... just to demonstrate: Minimal example of producing such a warning from this code: https://3v4l.org/bQbWN#v7.4.33 . Now with the offending code commented out, the warning goes away: https://3v4l.org/eHZtb#v7.4.33 . Obviously we don't know what get_promotion_widgets really does without consulting the Elementor source code, but presumably it does not return an array - or at least, doesn't always return an array. Therefore this bit of code probably ought to check the returned result before shoving it straight into a loop. But that's for the Elementor devs to sort out.

You can force to iterate over an array. foreach ((array) Api::get_promotion_widgets() as $widget_data ).

What if you replace Api::get_promotion_widgets() with Api::get_promotion_widgets() || [] or Api::get_promotion_widgets() ?? []

This is not an actual solution to the problem...
